# Why is lower semicontinuity important for epi-convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization

Why is the lower semicontinuity property important for epi-convergence (and, on the contrary, upper semicontinuity is not desirable)?

A simple example would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the definition of epi-convergence is made for lsc functions only. Even if this was not the case, the limit would be lsc automatically. So, if a function is not lsc, you cannot hope to epi-approximate it by nicer functions, which is a main purpose of epi-convergence. (It is used to transfer information about the minima of nice functions to their epi-limit.)

But instead of saying that lsc property is important for epi-convergence, I would say that both lsc property and epi-convergence are important for the same subject: minimization of functions, and this is why they tend to come up together.

- Lower semicontinuity is useful because it ensures the function attains its minimum  on any compact set.
- Epi-convergence is useful because it allows us to find a minimum point of the limit as the limit of minimum points.

An upper semicontinuous function does not necessarily attain its minimum: e.g., 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} |x|,\quad &x\ne 0 \\ 1,\quad & x=0\end{cases}$$
Even if we somehow approximate $f$ by nice functions $f_n$, the limit of minima of $f_n$ won't give us the minimum of $f$; the latter just does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So, for example, if I have the indicator function defined as $I(x)=1$ for $x \leq 0$ and $I(x)=0$ for $x < 0$ (which is clearly usc) and I have the sequence $\{I_{\nu}\}$ with $\lim_{\nu \to \infty} I_{\nu}(x)=I(x)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, I can't say that $I_{\nu}(x)$ epi-converges to $I(x)$ because the latter is not lsc, right?

Comment: @ItaAtz Right, because the definition of epi-convergence will not be satisfied (recall that epi-convergence does not follow from pointwise convergence). Epi-convergence requires that whenever $x_n\to x$, $\liminf f_n(x_n)\ge f(x)$. In your case $I(0)=1$ but there are sequences $x_n$ for which $I_n(x_n)\to 0$.